# how to calculate traits of a collection of similar images using python

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing

I have a collection of 100 similar images in directory "/passes". What I mean by "similar", is that they are all images of the same card. Each image in this collection is slightly different. Some cards have the color green splattered over it, while other images have the color red splattered over it. The amount of green and red splattered over the card varys per card. Also some cards torn or are missing some of their parts, for example some of the cards may only be 50% of the card instead of a full card.

So what I'm trying to do is create a way to first calculate the percentage of the card that has green splattered over it, red splattered over it, and the percentage of the card that is torn, as in does not have red or green but also is missing part of the card. Second I'm trying to store it in a dataframe that stores the three traits (green, red, torn) for each card. Also, there's only one card in the whole collection that has 0 of each trait.

The following code is close, and for some cards its very accurate but for other cards it is very off, for example some cards that are missing 75% of their body are coming up as having some green or red when this is not the case. Finally, the card itself has a tannish red color that sometimes messes up the calculation when all I want is the primary color red that is splattered over the card. Is there anyone who can correct my following code so its more accurate?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image


def crop_card(image_path):
    # Open the image and convert it to RGB format
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    # Get the size of the image
    width, height = image.size
    # Calculate the dimensions of the card within the border
    card_width = int(width * 0.8)
    card_height = int(height * 0.8)
    card_left = int((width - card_width) / 2)
    card_top = int((height - card_height) / 2)
    card_right = card_left + card_width
    card_bottom = card_top + card_height
    # Crop the image to the dimensions of the card
    card_image = image.crop((card_left, card_top, card_right, card_bottom))
    # Get the size of the card image
    card_width, card_height = card_image.size
    return card_image, card_width, card_height


def gray_percentage(image_path):
    # Open the image and convert it to grayscale format
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("L")
    # Get the size of the image
    width, height = image.size
    # Initialize the count for gray pixels
    gray_count = 0
    # Loop through each pixel in the image
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            # Get the pixel value
            pixel = image.getpixel((x, y))
            # Check if the pixel is gray
            if pixel >= 60 and pixel <= 190:
                gray_count += 1
    # Calculate the percentage of gray pixels in the image
    gray_percentage = (gray_count / (width * height)) * 100
    return gray_percentage


def color_hue_percentage(card_image, hue_filter, hue_threshold):
    # Initialize the count for filtered color pixels
    color_count = 0
    # Initialize the count for dark pixels
    dark_count = 0

    # Get the size of the card image
    card_width, card_height = card_image.size
    
    # Loop through each pixel in the card image
    for x in range(card_width):
        for y in range(card_height):
            # Get the RGB values for the pixel
            r, g, b = card_image.getpixel((x, y))
            # Check if the pixel matches the filter
            if hue_filter(r, g, b, hue_threshold):
                color_count += 1
            # Check if the pixel is dark
            if r < 60 and g < 60 and b < 60:
                dark_count += 1

    # Calculate the percentage of color pixels in the card image
    color_percentage = (color_count / (card_width * card_height)) * 100
    # Calculate the percentage of dark pixels in the card image
    dark_percentage = (dark_count / (card_width * card_height)) * 100
    
    # Subtract 10% from the dark percentage if the color percentage is below 50%
    if color_percentage < 40:
        result = color_percentage + (0.2 * dark_percentage)
    else:
        # Add the dark percentage to the color percentage
        result = color_percentage + dark_percentage

    # Return the result
    return result if color_count > 0 else 0

# Green hue filter
def is_green(r, g, b, threshold):
    return g > r and g > b

def is_red_splatter(r, g, b, threshold):
    return r > threshold and g < 70 and b < 70

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set the image directory
    image_dir = "/passes"

    # Initialize an empty list to store the results
    results = []

    # Loop through each file in the directory
    for filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
        # Check if the file is a JPG image
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            # Get the full path of the image
            image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, filename)

            # Crop the card image
            card_image, card_width, card_height = crop_card(image_path)
            
            # Calculate the percentage of gray pixels in the card image
            gray_percentage_value = gray_percentage(image_path)

            # Calculate the percentage of green pixels in the card image
            green_percentage_value = color_hue_percentage(card_image, is_green, 0)

            # Calculate the percentage of red splatter pixels in the card image
            red_percentage_value = color_hue_percentage(card_image, is_red_splatter, 150)

            # Create a dictionary to store the results
            result_dict = {
                "image": filename,
                "gray_percent": gray_percentage_value,
                "green_percent": green_percentage_value,
                "red_percent": red_percentage_value,
            }

            # Append the dictionary to the results list
            results.append(result_dict)

    # Create a pandas dataframe from the results list
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)

    # Print the dataframe
    print(df)
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] -- to make this reproducible, you need to provide input data. -- your question is only useful to you, but to nobody else. it's not a question someone else will have. as such, it's not a good fit for this site. be mindful of that when expecting responses.

Comment: Like Christoph has said, without the data no one can work on your code. However, I can point out that you are basing your work on color, brightness, and if-else statements - which has its limits.
The field of image processing has many more [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(computer_vision)) and classifiers which could make your task much easier.
For starters, try making a [scatter plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) with the percentage of red pixels on one axis, and green on another. Can you spot any patterns?

Comment: should I adjust my question by adding a link to the collection of images? Would that be enough to answer my question? I'll also go and look into image processing features and making the scatter plot to see if I can spot any patterns.